# Highcharts xAxis padding is lost when navigator when zooming in and out and can't get the padding back when zoom out

Tags: highcharts, zooming, navigator

I am using highcharts where I need extra padding on my chart. When I use navigator and zoom in   I the padding is lost - which is fine as I am zooming in. However when I zoom out using Navigator I don't get my padding back. Alternatively if I use the zoom button on chart I get the padding back (I would expect the same behaviour from navigator as well when I try to zoom out).

I've copied a sample chart form Highcharts Demo on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gajjargaurav/RULh9/5/ with Navigator and http://jsfiddle.net/gajjargaurav/RULh9/4/ with Zoom button

The padding I have set is as below for my sample,

```
xAxis: {
            maxPadding: 0.22, //Prevent chart going off the screen on the right
            minPadding: 0.22,
            tickPosition: 'outside'
        }
```

The question is, how I can get the navigator to behave like the zoom button does when I try to zoom out using navigator?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gajjargaurav/RULh9/12 fixes the problem of padding to some extent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately min/maxPadding works only for initial state. If you want to improve your range in that way, I advice to use `afterSetExtremes` event handler, and there setup new extremes( just increase that one you get).

Note: When setting new extremes in afterSetExtremes, will call another afterSetExtremes. Make sure. Make sure that you will not create infinite loop (add some flag checking if extremes are already improved, or not).

Comment: Hi @Pawel I followed you advice and came up with a fix but there is still an issue if I have flags on the series as now the flags are lagging behind while navigating using handles. Here is my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gajjargaurav/RULh9/12/ . This may work for others but I have many flags on my actual implementation and it  doesn't look good if flgs are lagging behind on chart.

Comment: I think you need to set `liveRedraw: false` for scrollbar, see: http://jsfiddle.net/RULh9/13/

Comment: Thankyou for the quick answer. Unfortunately we like the liveRedraw as it is a great feature to make the chart zoom very easy to use. Is this a bug in highcharts, or is this by design? Or we are using the padding for something it was not intended to do? The main reason we have the padding is to ensure flags ploted right at the beginning (or the end) of a time series are displayed fully and not cut off.

Comment: The problem is that using `afterSetExtremes` is only a workaround - so it may require some changes like disabling liveRedraw. Other options you can try to set is disable animation while doing extra zoom: http://jsfiddle.net/RULh9/15/

Comment: It is probably subject to separate thread but I was kind of hoping that navigator can accept padding from the chart it is bound to and does that implicitly. However your solution works for me

Comment: Use [UserVoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general) for asking new features and voting for existing one :)